# My object is being called has different values even though I had assigned value for it

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

I am currently doing my homework that requires me to create a dispenser machine system, which the below code is only a part extracted from my actual code, but it contains the core of the problem i faced.

Console Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L3Ij.png)

As shown in the console, the dispenser show 50 50 50 50 which is the default value if the constructor is called using `dispenserType()` instead of `dispenserType(int item[], int c[])`

However, if i were to move the for loop in main, into `staffDispenser()`, the values will be remember and will show the values exactly as inputted by me.

So I was assuming that whenever i call `dispenserType dt;`, it somehow calls `dispenserType()` constructor which ultimately overwrites everything to 50 again. I identified the issue but I don't know any fixes for this, I am expected to call the for loop function in another class called `customerDispenser()`, not in `staffDispenser()`. Is there anyway for me to use the `dispenserType` class function in other classes without it calling `dispenserType()` constructor again just to overwrite my values back to 50?

#note: I cannot remove `dispenserType()` nor `dispenserType(int item[], int c[])` since both are required in my homework.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dispenserType
{
private:
    int numberOfItems[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    int cost[4] = {0,0,0,0};
public:
    dispenserType()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        numberOfItems[i] = 50;
        cost[i] = 50;
       }
    }
    dispenserType(int item[], int c[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<4;i++){
            numberOfItems[i] = item[i];
            cost[i] = c[i];
        }
    }
    int getNoOfItems(int i)
    {
        int j = i;
        return numberOfItems[j];
    }
    int getCost(int i)
    {
        int j = i;
        return cost[j];
    }
    void makeSale(int i)
    {
        int j = i;
        numberOfItems[j] -= 1;
    }
};

void staffDispenser()
{
    char choice;
    int item[4];
    int cost[4];

    cout << endl << "Do you want to asign values manually for each items? (Y for yes, N for no): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cout << "Enter the number of " << name[i] << ": ";
            cin >> item[i];
            cout << "Enter the cost of " << name[i] << " (in cents): ";
            cin >> cost[i];
            
        }
        dispenserType dt = dispenserType(item, cost);
    }
    else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n') {
        dispenserType dt = dispenserType();
        cout << endl << "Each item is set to 50 in quantity and also cost 50 cents" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    dispenserType dt;
    int item[4];
    int cost[4];
    
    staffDispenser();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        juice[i] = dt.getNoOfItems(i);
        c[i] = dt.getCost(i);
        }
    
        for (int i =0; i<4; i++){
            cout << item[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i =0; i<4; i++){
            cout << cost[i] << " ";
        }

}
```

Comment: You seem to expect that `dispenserType dt;`  in `main` and `staffDispenser` are somehow connected? They are not, they are two completely separate objects

Comment: The `dt` variable in your `staffDispenser` function is a local (temporary) object and not the same one as that of the same name declared in `main`. This is elementary C++ stuff and you need to re-read your basic C++ text book.

Comment: Whenever you see `[type] [identifier];` like `dispenserType dt;` or `[type] [identifier] = [initializer];` like `dispenserType dt = dispenserType(item, cost);` it is defining a new object unrelated to any other instance of that type. Your code initializes a `dispenserType` and then discards it at the end of `staffDispenser`. It also initializes a default constructed instance in `main` and never modifies it. You need a single instance that you pass around your functions.

Comment: Tangential: rather than having two separate arrays, a single array of `structs` would make more sense.  Try it, see how it simplifies your code.

Comment: oh yeah i somehow forgotten pass by reference

Comment: I managed to fixed it, i declared a global ```dispenserType dt;``` then put ```dispenserType &dt``` as arguments in functions that requires such class function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `dt` in `main()` and in `staffDispenser` are two distinct variables. The changes done to `dt` variable in `staffDispenser` are local to that function, it is not reflected into the main.

If you want to update the `dt` variable of main in `staffDispenser` function you need to pass it by reference.

```cpp
void staffDispenser(dispenserType &dt) {
}
```

And from main call `staffDispenser` as follows:

```cpp
dispenserType dt;
int item[4];
int cost[4];
    
staffDispenser(dt);  // pass dt by reference
```

You also need to remove following two lines from `staffDispenser` function

```cpp
dispenserType dt = dispenserType(item, cost);

dispenserType dt = dispenserType();
```

Comment: my program is rather complicated as i did both customer and staff where staff would set the items in dispenser while customer can view the item details in the dispenser, im currently still thinking on how should i pass it as reference from staff functions to customer function since they are not connected to each other directly

Comment: As per the code you have shown, it will not produce the result which you are expecting.

Comment: i thought of a plan to declare ```dispenserType &dt;``` in between the class and function classes, then i put ```dispenserType &dt``` as argument in each function that will call the class, and inside the class for example ```staffDispenser```, i'll put ```dt = dispenserType(item, cost);```

Comment: just tested it out, it worked.